# Laravel dependency Injection for post request

Tags: laravel

I have seen from laracast videos that one of the ways to take and validate the post request is dependency injection as follows:

```
 public function store(ArticlesRequest $request){
        Auth::user()->articles()->save(new Article($request->all()));
        return redirect('articles');

    }
```

can anyone explain how the post request is passed to the class ArticleRequest? when I try something like this it wont work:

```
 public function store(){
        $request=new ArticlesRequest();
        Auth::user()->articles()->save(new Article($request->all()));
        return redirect('articles');

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses something called ["reflection"](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) on function signatures to attempt to automatically pass them what they need. Trying to do it in the function's code instead of its signature won't work - Laravel doesn't look there.

A bit more info on reflection: http://culttt.com/2014/07/02/reflection-php/